# Isomorphism with Jacobson radical

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

In a proof I am reading it seems that the writer is using the following isomorphism for a finite dimensional $K$-algebra A and a idempotent $e \in A$ (the idempotent is not central per sé):

$e(\text{rad} A )/e (\text{rad }^2 A) \cong \text{rad}(eA)/(\text{rad }^2 (eA))$, where $rad$ stands for the Jacobson radical.

To me this seems a direct consequence of $e(\text{rad} A ) \cong \text{rad} (eA )$, this I don't seem to be able to proof.

I attempted constructing an epimorphism from $A \rightarrow eA$ by $a \mapsto ea$ but this fails to be a homomorphism since $ab \mapsto eab \neq (ea) (eb) $

Working with the characterization of invertibility of course wouldn't work since $eA$ isn't a unital ring. As a matter of fact, all characterizations I know of require the existence of a unit since non unitary rings needn't contain maximal ideals.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

edit: I will give some context to what I am doing. The book I am reading is 'Elements of the representation theory of associative algebras' by Assem, Simson and Skowronski. This is an exert of the proof, in which my question arose, $e_a$ here plays the role of the idempotent $e$ in my question above.

A routine calculation shows that the A-module homomorphism $\phi : e_a(\text{rad}A) → e_a(\text{rad}A/\text{rad}^2A)$ given by $e_ax \rightarrow e_a(x + \text{rad}^2A)$  admits $e_a(\text{rad}^2A)$ as a kernel. Consequently
$ e_a($rad$A / $rad$^2 A) \cong e_a($rad$A)/e_a($rad$^2A) \cong $rad$(e_aA)/$rad$^2(e_a A)$

Comment: Are you familiar with the notion of radical for $A$-modules?

Comment: No I am not. I suppose the definition would be very similar. For an $A$-module $M$ the radical would be the intersection of all maximal submodules of $M$?

Comment: Right, that is the correct definition. Now note that $A \to e A, a \mapsto ea$ is a homomorphism of right $A$-modules.

Comment: @MatthiasKlupsch That is not a correct definition, strictly speaking. In $2\mathbb Z/4\mathbb Z$, the zero ideal is a maximal submodule, but the radical is *the entire module.* Some extra condition is needed on the maximal ideals considered. I think this involves guaranteeing that $(R/M)R\neq 0$.

Comment: @M.v.Roozendaal Well, there are [two characterizations for radicals of rngs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobson_radical#Equivalent_characterizations) at Wikipedia, so you should have been able to find those. Unfortunately $eA$ is not usually a ring, so you're in need of the analogues for modules over rngs, which are not as well recorded in wikipedia. I think, possibly, the right definition is the intersection of maximal submodules $M\leq eA$ satisfying $(eA/M)A\neq 0$.

Comment: @M.v.Roozendaal Armed with this, you would just need to establish a *module* homomorphism (rather than a ring homomorphism) from $A$ to $eA$ to see their radicals.

Comment: @M.v.Roozendaal Could you also provide the portion of the text you are examining, or at least a citation?

Comment: @rschwieb I shall do this as soon as possible (I'm still rather new so finding a clever way of doing so might take some time). Anyhow I can tell you that I use the book Elements of the representation theory of associative algebras Vol. 1 by Assem, Simon and Skowronski. They btw do define the radical of a module as I above stated, Why would you say that the radical is the entire module in your counterexample?

Comment: When you mention "an author" it is usually a good ideal to actually give the name and title of what you are reading, as that helps build a context for your question.

Comment: And, btw, "per se" does not mean what you seem to think it does ;-)

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez was that "ideal" typo in the comment two above intentional??

Comment: I am now doing what I should have been doing some time ago, that is reading the chapter which explains radicals of modules... I think it is well explained here and with this information I think I should be able to solve my problem, I am sorry to bother you all by missing such a thing.

Comment: @M.v.Roozendaal The radical is the entire module because that lines up with the commutative, non-unital definition of the radical as a ring (the module and ring versions should always line up in this respect.) Central nilpotents should always lie in the radical (because they annihilate the special subcollection of simple modules.)

Comment: In the book you are reading (now that we know what book you are reading) rings have units. Moreover, $eA$ is not a ring in any meaningful sense in that context.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Pardon me for my silly question, but do you mean it is not a unitary ring? And if so, In my opinion saying it is not a ring in any meaningful sense in that context is perhaps a bit of a stretch, no? The only part of the definition which fails is (half of) the part of the existence of a two sided unit, and even so this part of the definition is not necessary to define a ring.

Comment: It may be true that multiplication of $A$ does induce a multiplication map $eA \times eA \to eA$ on $e A$ making it a non-unital ring, but I would agree with Mariano, this structure is not that meaningful in contrast to the module structure which is obtained by restricting multiplication on $A$ only to a map $eA \times A \to eA$.  @rschwieb : You are right, in general, this is not the correct definition. In the context of finitely generated modules over finite dimensional algebras, however, I see no problem.

Comment: @MatthiasKlupsch Yes, reexamining what the poster's context for what did not have unity now, I agree with you.